# Can't pass the lcm solution task in the Yandex Contest competition

Tags: c++

This is my source code, which I try to pass to the least common multiplier task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "algorithm"

using namespace std;
using ll = long long;
using ld = long double;

long long gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (b > 0) {
        a %= b;
        swap(a, b);
    }
    return a;
}

long long lcm(int a, int b) {
    return a / gcd(a, b) * b;
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(nullptr);

    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    cout << lcm(x, y);
}
```

I get a Wrong Answer 11:
[image]

What's wrong with it? I tried many times. Please, help me!

Comment: Have you tried to debug your application locally?  For example, are there any cases where `gcd` might return `0`?

Comment: Yes, it returns 0 as expected.

Comment: Then what happens when you divide `a` with `0`? What happens when you divide *anything* with `0`?

Comment: It returns 0 in my computer. Anyway, I added the check for gcd(a,b) == 0 and in the case return 0, but I didn't help. Still wrong answer 11.

Comment: If your `gcd` function returns `0` then it's wrong. `0` can never be a greatest common divisor to anything.

Comment: It returns 0, if a and b are 0, in any other case it returns a `non-zero` number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232799/discussion-between-intolighter-and-some-programmer-dude).

Comment: I wonder if Yandex codebase has `using ll = long long;` somewhere in it...

Comment: Didn't understand what you meant @Evg. But that row wasn't the reason for the fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about negative numbers? Try calculating the GCD(abs(x), abs(y)), it's the same as GCD(x, y)